# Slicing off a subarray of a given shape

Tags: python, numpy

Let A by a d-dimensional array in numpy and let sh be a d-tuple of positive integers. Is there an elegant way how to define a sub-array

> A[0:sh[0], 0:sh[1], ..., 0:sh[d-1]]

("lower left" subtensor)? Something like A[sh] or A[*sh] which actually works...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
A[tuple(map(slice, sh))]
```

Build a tuple of slice objects out of `sh`.